# Spark SQL DataFrame write to S3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark-SQL where I want to retrieve records from Redshift & write them to S3. I am referring to this link [Spark-Redshift](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift) ...I am able to print the schema of DataFrame but I am not able to write to S3..It is throwing error :

```
 error:  S3ServiceException:The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.,Status 403,Error InvalidAccessKeyId
```

What should I need to do to write to S3 ?? Any other way to save Redshift data to S3 using Spark??